# Why the "identifiant" aren't replaced by the email-address in Empathy?

Tags: 12.10, empathy, telepathy

Since the upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 12.10, I can not see the email address from my Windows Live friends in Empathy.

Essentially, when I put the mouse over a contact, a little box will appear. In this box, the field that should containing the email address from my contact, displays (for example): **f1414df1f4g1g0@messenger.live.com**

*Edit: I just added a Facebook Chat Profil in Empathy, and I have the same problem with the identifiant.*

Is this normal ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).